# Error download images

Tags: ios, json, swift, image, url

I am new to Swift , I am parsing my JSON by using ObjectMapper but I want data to be displayed in TableView. But I have a problem with download image 
I using extension UIImageView func downloadFrom

My problem :

> invalid redeclaration of 'download From(url:ContentMode:)'

My Code :

```
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell

        let strUrl = categoty[indexPath.row].picture

        cell.titleCategory.text = self.categoty[indexPath.row].title

        cell.imageCategory.downloadFrom(url: URL(string: strUrl!)!)

        return cell
    }
}

extension UIImageView {
    func downloadFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
                self.image = image
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It esentially means that you have declared two functions with the same name.. just rename your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you have written the function same function with the same name twice in your code.

Look for a duplicate implementation of this method in your code:

```
func downloadFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
```